# Convert radiation density into temp in degrees kelvin

Tags: temperature, thermal-radiation, cosmic-microwave-background

in the 1948 paper by [Alpher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Asher_Alpher) he gives a present radiation density in gm per cm cubed. how is that converted to a temp of 5 degree kelvin

Comment: Which paper? The [Alpher, Bethe, Gamow paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpher%E2%80%93Bethe%E2%80%93Gamow_paper)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The temperature of photon and its energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59456/)

Answer (score 2):

By using the integrated energy density of a blackbody radiation field, which is
$$u  = \frac{\pi^2}{15}\frac{(k_BT)^4}{(\hbar c)^3}\ .$$

Divide this by $c^2$ to get the equivalent mass density.